# File uploading with XMLHttpRequest Undefined index

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I've searched around and could not find the answer to my problem. I've tried tons of stuff and it didnt work.

Whenever I'm sending a file via XMLHttpRequest to my swfupload.php my swfupload.php doesnt see the `$_FILES`

Here is my HTML

```
<form id="FlashUpload">
    <div class="fUpload">
        <label for="fileToUpload">Select a swf to Upload</label><br />
        <input type="file" name="upfile" id="fileToUpload" onchange="fileSelected();" accept="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        <input type="button" value="Upload" id="buttonToUpload" onclick="uploadFlash();"/>
        <div id="fError"></div>
    </div>
    <div style=" display:none;" class="meter animate">
        <span style="width: 0%;"><span></span></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

and here is my javascript file

```
function uploadFlash() {
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload');

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("upfile", file.files[0]);


    client.open("post", "/swfupload.php", true);
    client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    client.send(file);  /* Send to server */ 

    client.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (client.readyState === 4 && client.status === 200) {
            var return_data = client.responseText;
            $("#fError").text(return_data);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the part where I get my error in PHP

```
if (!isset($_FILES['upfile']['error'])) {
    throw new RuntimeException($_FILES['upfile']['error']);
}
```

I'm not sure if it has anything to do with me being in WAMP

The error: [image]

Comment: Check what you are getting by printing out `$_FILES` in PHP ?

Comment: @Aditya I've changed the PHP a bit and it gives me the Undefined index error as you can see. var_dump($_FILES) gives me the text: array

Comment: Yes in that array do u see an index `upfile` or some other index?

Comment: @Aditya No its empty.

Comment: Can you show us what `print_r($_FILES)` contains?

Comment: @Aditya http://i.imgur.com/wEdJtGB.png

Comment: alert(file); and check ?

Comment: Try like this `var files = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files;` and   `formData.append("upfile", files[0]);`

Comment: @Aditya Still nothing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48986/discussion-between--and-aditya)